# How to get base tenant and guest tenant from currently logged in user in MS Graph

Tags: uwp

We're building a common control which needs to obtain the base tenant for the user, and possibly guest tenant info if different from base tenant from MS Graph.

Thanks

Comment: Looking for code sample.We've researched the graph.microsoft.com API reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the topic [Get started with Microsoft Graph in a universal Windows 10 app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/uwp) and download the [Microsoft Graph Connect Sample for UWP (Library)](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-connect-sample) that the above article is based on. Besides, there is also a [REST version of this sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-connect-rest-sample).